# Set two-arrow key combinations to [PageUp|PageDn|Home|End]

Tags: keyboard

I have a new mac and am unable to recall how to enable the following key mappings:

- Up-Right -> Page Up
- Down-Right -> Page Dn
- Up -Left -> Home
- Down-Left -> End

Those combinations are **working on my other macbook**. I can not however recall where/how those are enabled. I have looked in the following and not found them:

- Karabiner (aka `KeyRemap4Mac`)
- System Preferences | Keyboard  (looked through all the panels
  and clicked all the buttons)

My recollection is there were a *single* option selected that enabled all *four* of those mappings.  I did think it were in `Karabiner` (aka `KeyRemap4Mac`)  but can not find it .

Comment: if you're on a 'short' keyboard [laptop, iMac etc], Fn + arrow keys do that

Comment: @Tetsujin  Yes, using Fn-Arrow does work - but that is not convenient. I am referring to *just* the two-arrow combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found it - and yes it is Karabiner but not in the expected place instead under "Simulataneous key presses"

[image]

There is a similar way by using the Right-Option key:

> Change Option-R Key

[image]